# Вставка email админа в форму wp

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть файл с обработкой формы php. Нужно, чтобы email брался с админки, а не вписывался вручную в файл. Сайт на WordPress.

```html
<?php
    $recepient = "email@df.com";


 $name = trim($_POST['name']);
 $tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
 $from = trim($_POST['from']);


 // формируем тело сообщения
 $message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $tel \nEmail: $email \nВопрос: $comment";
 

 $pagetitle = "Сообщение с Задать вопрос";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
?>
```

Comment: можно глобальную переменную добавить

Answer (score 1):

Адрес почты администратора хранится в базе. Получить его следует таким способом:

```
$recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
```